# How to remove timestamps from one timepoint to another from time column in python

Tags: python, time-series

I have a dataset containing timestamps upto miliseconds and I need to compare the timestamps between two datasets. I realise one dataset has more dates than the other and I want to try to remove these dates but as it goes until miliseconds point im not sure how to do this correctly. The column looks like below and basically i want to remove the entries for 13/04 only. I don't have any code to share as I am not sure how to do this at all.

```
time    
2017-04-13 00:40:59.333666  
2017-04-13 00:41:27.844666  
2017-04-13 00:41:32.146663  
2017-04-13 00:41:46.394636  
2017-04-13 00:41:46.556656  
2017-04-13 00:41:46.597766
2017-04-13 00:41:47.595566  
2017-04-13 00:41:49.063366
```

Comment: You want to remove only the date timestamps?

Comment: yes only the date as the other data set begins at 2017-04-14 so i want to remove from this dataset 13/04 to begin from 14/04 so that it matches with the other dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have the dates in a string:

```
dates = 'time    \n2017-04-13 00:40:59.333666  \n2017-04-13 00:41:27.844666  \n2017-04-13 00:41:32.146663  \n2017-04-13 00:41:46.394636  \n2017-04-13 00:41:46.556656  \n2017-04-13 00:41:46.597766\n2017-04-13 00:41:47.595566  \n2017-04-13 00:41:49.063366  \n'
```

We just create a new list without the dates by just replacing the date with nothing.

```
lines = [x for x in dates.split('\n')]
new_list = [x.replace("2017-04-13 ", '') for x in lines]
```

Comment: thanks but my list of these timestamps are much longer than what i showed here.. is there a better way to remove by placing a condition like "if timestamp is = 13.04" then remove?

Comment: If the dates are exactly the same length every time you can just check the first 10 characters to check the date.